# How to post photos to facebook iphone fbconnect

Tags: iphone, image, post, photo, fbconnect

Hi I'm using FBConnect to post to facebook, now I need to post photos from library or taken with the cam, does anyone has a clue how to do this ?? I've searched in google but I can't find a piece of code that works for me. I've found this method:

```
FBRequest *uploadPhotoRequest = [FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self];
     [uploadPhotoRequest call:@"photos.upload" params:args];
```

but in my fbconnect i have this one instead: (I think the version of the api is different)

```
 [_fbRequest call:(NSString *) params:(NSDictionary *) dataParam:(NSData *)];
```

Also I'm using this method to post to the wall:

```
 - (void)postToWall {       FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog
 alloc] init] autorelease];
 dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Enter your message:";   
 dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@ Esta conectado desde TravelFan iPhone App\",\"caption\":\"Viajar te cambia la vida\",\"description\":\"\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://www.travelfan.com.mx/content/templates/default/images/logo_travel.jpg\",\"href\":\"http://www.travelfan.com.mx/\"}]}",
 _facebookName];   
dialog.actionLinks = @"[{\"text\":\"Obten TravelFan
 App!\",\"href\":\"http://www.travelfan.com.mx/\"}]";   [dialog show];  
 }
```

In this method I can send an image but not as a photo its just for the app logo and its an attachment.

Can anyone tell how to post photos to the wall pls ?? 
Any help is apreciated XD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now post photos on your wall with `requestWithGraphPath` method as follows.

```
NSData *yourImageData= UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Your text with picture", @"message", yourImageData, @"source", nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: What is facebook? is it a FBrequest?

Comment: Should I need to change in the Application Settings in my app account for supporting Graph? Please reply

Comment: facebook is object of Facebook class. you can find that in default sdk provided by facebook.

Comment: i want to upload more than one images is it possible? help me please

Comment: Not yet found out the way. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291741/upload-multiple-photos-on-facebook-using-batch-request) that is the best try I guess

Answer (score 0):

> The requestWithGraphPath method is non-blocking - meaning it will complete before the photo is actually uploaded. You'll know when the photo is finished uploading by implementing the following in your FBRequestDelegate