# Upload multiple photos on Facebook using Batch Request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I had done following code with reference to following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353117/facebook-connect-batch-requests-and-fql-error-problem) to create batch request for uploading multiple photos in Facebook.

I had got some solution for uploading multiple photos on Facebook through this [Facebook graph API.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)

**CODE:**

```
    NSString *jsonRequest1 = @"{ \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"me/photos\" , \"body\": \"Hello 1\", \"attached_files\": \"file1\" }";
    NSString *jsonRequest2 = @"{ \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"me/photos\" , \"body\": \"Hello 2\", \"attached_files\": \"file2\" }";
    NSString *jsonRequestsArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[ %@, %@ ]", jsonRequest1, jsonRequest2];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonRequestsArray,@"batch",nil];
    [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image1) forKey:@"file1"];
    [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image2) forKey:@"file2"];
    [objFacebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Now when I am running this code I got the following output.

**Result Dictionary in** `- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result`

```
(
        {
        body = "{\"error\":0,\"error_description\":\"File file1 has not been attached\"}";
        code = 400;
        headers =         (
                        {
                name = "HTTP/1.1";
                value = "400 Bad Request";
            },
                        {
                name = "Content-Type";
                value = "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        body = "{\"error\":0,\"error_description\":\"File file2 has not been attached\"}";
        code = 400;
        headers =         (
                        {
                name = "HTTP/1.1";
                value = "400 Bad Request";
            },
                        {
                name = "Content-Type";
                value = "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8";
            }
        );
    }
)
```

I don't know how this files attached.. Can anyone help me to figure out this problem.

Is there any change in my code then please let me know.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is UIImage that I want to upload on Facebook.

Comment: Have you tried going to this site: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/
looks very helpful
Hope this helps

Comment: I had seen this link before asking question here dear..

Comment: Does it work with file1 only?

Comment: Mehul, if you got the solutions, can you please post your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the new integrated Facebook API's in iOS 6 to do this instead of Facebook's API: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=306 there's a golden WWDC video for all social tasks. Plus using the new API's in iOS 6 is MUCH faster then using Facebooks.

Comment: What about supporting to iOS5 ?

Comment: If you want to support iOS 5 for Facebook, you'll have to dive into Facebooks API's. However most active users of iOS are on iOS 6. Since Apple makes it so simple to upgrade to iOS 6 from iOS 5. So I wouldn't worry about supporting iOS 5.

Comment: "Most active users of iOS are on iOS 6" ? Any statistics ?

Comment: http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-6-sees-record-breaking-adoption-rate-more-than-twice-as-quick-compared-to-ios-5-in-the-first-two-days/  Since the settings app updates uber easily.... It's no wonder.

Answer (score 0):

For your NSDictionary of parameters ,use the NSData representation, instead of directly using the UIImage object.

Depending on the compression format of the images you are trying to upload, you'll need to use a different method to convert the UIImage to NSData.  Here are two techniques, one for PNG and one for JPEG

```
//...cut...
[params setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.jpegImage, 0.8) forKey:@"file1"];
[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.pngImage) forKey:@"file2"];
//...cut...
```

This is a tutorial from the Facebook Developer blog that shows something similar (although it is for a video, and not the batch API), and one significant difference from your code is that the parameter passed is in NSData representation, not UIImage.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/

Comment: Dear Obuseme.. The same error had been occurred as I had shown in my question.. that File file1 has not been attached

Comment: Ok let me double check the obvious. The images are valid objects and representations of images, right?  Could you post the code where you are creating the objects?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you validating that the image objects are not nil.

Comment: I am sure the  image objects are not nil because I am posting pictures only

Comment: Please add this code at the end of the method  NSLog(@"image=%@ param=%@", self.image1, params); and show me the output please. Thx

Answer (score 0):

[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image1) forKey:@"file1"];

This should not be the data, it should be the path for that images. It will work fine if you provide a path instead of NSData.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for multiple file upload using FBgraph.

here is my code.

```
-(void) fbGraphCallback
{

FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc]initWithImage:imgView1.image];
FbGraphFile *graph_file1 = [[FbGraphFile alloc]initWithImage:imgView2.image];

NSString *jsonRequest1 = @"{ \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"me/photos\" , \"body\": \"First Image\", \"attached_files\": \"file1\" }";

NSString *jsonRequest2 = @"{ \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"me/photos\" , \"body\": \"Second Image\", \"attached_files\": \"file2\" }";

NSString *jsonRequestsArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[ %@, %@ ]", jsonRequest1, jsonRequest2];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary     dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonRequestsArray,@"batch",nil];

[params setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file1"];
[params setObject:graph_file1 forKey:@"file2"];

[fbgraph doGraphPost:@"" withPostVars:params];

}
```

Thanks mehul.

Answer (score -1):

You are adding the binary to the Dictionary incorrectly.  Take a look at the file upload method in [Facebook's sample app](https://github.com/booyah/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/8470eb9bdc0449996bcfd2f2f954c92a5e33bae6/sample/DemoApp/Classes/DemoAppViewController.m).  You should be able to easily adopt Facebook's sample code to your app.

```
/** 
 * Upload a photo.
 */
-(IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender 
{
  NSString *path = @"http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  UIImage *img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 img, @"picture",
                                 nil];
  [_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
  [img release];
}
```

Comment: You are right dear but Is your code uploads two images at the same time on Facebook??

Comment: @Jennis: I did read the question.  Did you try to adopt the code from the sample app to Mehul's code? You can add multiple image binaries to the Dictionary with "file1" and "file2" as the keys.