# how to Upload more then 1 image at a time using FBGraph for ios?

Tags: ios, fb-graph

I want upload more then 1 image using FBgraph.

I am also try for append all image data with main request body.

BUT it's only upload last image , So how to manage this ?

Comment: I Got Solution check the link for detail.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17023897/2181751