# Facebook error getting image on post

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to post photos to facebook iphone fbconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959961/how-to-post-photos-to-facebook-iphone-fbconnect)

I am using FB SDK and getting an error while uploading picture on FB post from my app 
in my view did load i have and UIImageView which has an image that i need to be posted on FB the code of the view did load

```
ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 65)];
ImageView.center = CGPointMake(42, 43);
[View addSubview:ImageView];
```

and in my method of FB post i did this

```
   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]init];
   image = ImageView.image;

   NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];


   [params setObject:@"LINK_HERE" forKey:@"link"];


// due to this line below, i am getting an error :
// "[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170fa0e0" 
// and if use http link instead of image(UIImage) it works, but i want to use my image
   [params setObject:image forKey:@"picture"];    

   [params setObject:@"NAME_HERE" forKey:@"name"];
   [params setObject:@"DEC_HERE" forKey:@"description"];

// Invoke the dialog
       [self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

How should i use my UIImage inside this code ... any idea ??

Comment: http://yashesh87.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/social-framework-integration-iphone-sdk-ios/ easy way to upload image.

Comment: Check my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959961/how-to-post-photos-to-facebook-iphone-fbconnect/6960239#6960239

Answer (score 0):

You can only upload URL based images in Facebook dialog method..Images generated within the app or within app bundle cant be uploaded..

To upload those images you have to use graph API

sample code

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    image, @"source", 
    @"caption desc", @"message",             
    nil];
  [facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/me/photos?access_token=%@", self.facebook.accessToken]
  andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: getting error Error: HTTP status code: 400

Answer (score 0):

you can post your image simply like this

```
UIImage *imgSource = {insert your image here};
NSString *strMessage = @"Images Description";
NSMutableDictionary* photosParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     imgSource,@"source",
                                     strMessage,@"message",
                                     nil];

[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                 andParams:photosParams
                             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                               andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: getting error Error: HTTP status code: 400

Answer (score -2):

There is a sample app in facebook sdk, please check that.

You can also check out these tutorials:

- [Facebook Tutorial for iOS: How To Use Facebook’s New Graph API from your iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app)
- [Facebook Tutorial for iOS: How To Get a User Profile with Facebook’s New Graph API from your iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app)
- [Facebook Tutorial for iOS: How To Post to a User’s Wall, Upload Photos, and Add a Like Button from your iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app)

Comment: read this also...https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/#step7

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Rikesh    why u r nt giving the answer then..for me the sample project is best way to deal with ur problem..as well as i have given the link which gives him the description...

Comment: @Rikesh   and why down vote...if u have any idea of iOS..check the link...